# Emacs RegExp - How to select CamelCase word?

Tags: regex, emacs

I am still learning Emacs' regular expression and trying to select CamelCase word for highlighting.

Here is my regular expression
`\\([A-Z]*\\)\\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*[(]`

I thought it should only select word like this => `HelloWorld.hello(`
and it does. It does highlight the word completely.
But it also selects the non-camelcase word => `helloWorld.hello(`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to specify that you want your string to *start with* capital letter: `^[A-Z]`

Comment: What of the sample input is matched? All of it or only starting with the dot? Depending on that either Anderssons idea is to follow otherwise mine (deleted but I can make a corresponding answer).

Comment: If all of the sample input is matched, then make sure that you do not apply the regex case-insensitively.

Comment: @Andersson I think one thing I forgot to mention is that [A-Z] expression
is not working.

Comment: @Jen-ChiehShen , you mean you tried something like `(^[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+).[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*[(]` and it's not working?

Comment: @Yunnosch How am I able to apply case sensitively? I think the issue is that the regular expression in not case sensitive.

Comment: If `[A-Z]` does not work, does `[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]`? You need to find out the features of your regex flavor.

Comment: @Yunnosch None of them work. I tried that already. :(

Comment: Sorry, that is a question you will have to answer yourself by reading the Emacs regex docu. It will also tell you whether `[A-Z]` is supposed to work.

Comment: Does `\[A\]` or `\\[A\\]` work on an existing "A"?

Comment: You state "and it does", referring to the regex selecting "HelloWorld.hello(". So it does highlight that string. Completley or only part of it?

Comment: @Andersson I am confuse with why [[:digit:]] works but [[:upper:]] does not work.

Comment: @Yunnosch It does highlight the word completely. But I do not want `helloWorld.hello(` to be highlight.

Comment: Read the docu on case sensitivity of regexes. Meanwhile show how exactly you apply the regex. Show the whole commandline (or quote here what exactly your are typing, if it is not visible anywhere). Maybe somebody here knows the docu by heart. But it is your job to read it. If you are sure that a picture is helpful for clarifying your context, this is the rare case where showing one might be helpful. (Usually readers here do not appreciate pictures of text at all.)

Comment: This looks like the rigth part of the docu. Do you know how to set those variables? https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Controlling-case-sensitivity.html https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Searching-and-Case.html

Comment: In which way does `[[:upper:]] not work? Does not select anything or selects too much?

Comment: @Yunnosch Oh I see, I have my logic wrong using RegExp. That's why this isn't working. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Andersson Since you seem interested and competent. Do you have an idea why exactly the change described in OPs own answer has helped? I mean the original version, with `t` instead of `nil`.

Comment: @Yunnosch , actually It was interesting for me just to find correct regex, but I'm not familiar with Emacs

Answer (score 2):

Okay, this is actually simple, once you know the answer.
Adding

```el
(let ((case-fold-search nil))
  (do-something-with-regexp))
```

actually solved my issue.

Comment: Reading here, I think it should be `nil` not `t`. https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Controlling-case-sensitivity.html

Comment: @Yunnosch Thanks! I do not know why, but setting it `t' solved my issue, but for sake of any reason I will just set it to nil here.

Comment: NO! Describe here what did help you, not what others (me) believe should have helped. With a bit of luck, somebody can explain **why** it did help you. Just make sure that it really is the `t` which helped. I.e. try again and also with `nil` and back to `t`.

Comment: You could edit your question, adding at the end something like "I found something which helped, see my answer below. But could somebody explain why it helped exactly?"

Comment: The variable name in this answer was mis-spelled initially, so I suspect some invalid testing occurred, which could explain the confusion over the correct value.